# Python behavior of string in loop

Tags: python, string, loops

In trying to capitalize a string at separators I encountered behavior I do not understand.  Can someone please explain why the string s in reverted during the loop?  Thanks.

```
s = 'these-three_words'  
seperators = ('-','_')  
for sep in seperators:  
    s = sep.join([i.capitalize() for i in s.split(sep)])  
    print s  
print s  

stdout:  
These-Three_words  
These-three_Words  
These-three_Words
```

Answer (score 6):

[`capitalize`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) turns the first character uppercase and the rest of the string lowercase.

In the first iteration, it looks like this:

```
>>> [i.capitalize() for i in s.split('-')]
['These', 'Three_words']
```

In the second iteration, the strings are the separated into:

```
>>> [i for i in s.split('_')]
['These-Three', 'words']
```

So running capitalize on both will then turn the T in Three lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`title()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

```
>>> s = 'these-three_words'
>>> print s.title()
These-Three_Words
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.capitalize` capitalizes the first character and lowercases the remaining characters.

Answer (score 2):

Capitalize() will return a copy of the string with **only its first character** capitalized. You could use this:

```
def cap(s):
    return s[0].upper() + s[1:]
```